# I have Residence Permit (Tier 2) from my former employer. I left UK and want to visit UK as a tourist

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visitor-visa, deception

I used to work in the UK under a Tier 2 visa, and my residence permit is valid until December 2017.  I left my Job in October 2015 and left the country.  Now I want to visit the UK as a tourist.

So, do I need a visit visa, or can I use the same residence permit which has validity till December 2017?

Also, I never received the notice of curtailment from the Home Office and I am not sure if my former employer ever reported my resignation to the Home Office.  Will this cause any problem in the visa process?

Answer (score 4):

Your intentions for entering the UK should (by law) always match your visa type. So you will need to apply for visitor's visa.

Comment: If you are coming to the UK from a country where you typically don't need a visa (e.g., the US), is it advisable to apply for a visa like you would if you had previously been refused entry?